# Delete greek letters in string

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I am pre-processing dirty text fields. I have managed to delete single characters and numbers, but there are still Greek letters (from formulas) that I want to delete altogether.
Any type of Greek letter can occur at any position in the string.
Any ideas how to do it?

```
select regexp_replace(' ω ω α ω alkanediylbis alkylimino bis alkanolpolyethoxylate   the formula where       straight   branched chain alkylene group also known     alkanediyl group that has   the range       carbon atoms and     least  carbon atoms   length   and   can   the same   different and are primary alkyl groups which contain     carbon atoms each   and   can   the same   different and are alkylene groups which contain   the range   from     carbon atoms each and   and   are the same   different numerals     the range       each ', '\W+', '')
```

Comment: do you need to delete only *single* greek characters or any greek characters?

Comment: any. they can also occur as  ωαω...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[Α-Ωα-ω]` will match the standard Greek alphabet. (Note that the `Α` here is a distinct character from the Latin `A`, though they probably look identical).

Some commonly-used symbols are outside of the standard alphabet, so at the very least, you probably want to match the whole [Greek Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_and_Coptic) using `[\u0370-\u03FF]`.

Unicode also has

- The [Greek Extended block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_Extended) containing letters with diacritics
- The [Coptic block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_(Unicode_block)) with some very similar-looking characters
- The [Mathematical Operators block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Operators) with its own `∆`/`∏`/`∑` symbols
- Several copies of the Greek alphabet in the [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols)

...and probably more.

Rather than trying to list everything you want to replace, it might be easier to list the things you want to keep. For example, to remove everything outside the printable [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) range:

```
select regexp_replace(
  'ABCΑαΒβΓγΔδΕεΖζΗηΘθΙιΚκΛλΜμΝνΞξΟοΠπΡρΣσςΤτΥυΦφΧχΨψΩω123',
  '[^\u0020-\u007E]', '', 'g'
);

 regexp_replace
----------------
 ABC123
```